# How to use Timepicker in android to control length of song

Tags: android, timepicker

How to use the TimePicker in android in order to control length of song? 
For example: when the user plays the song the user will then can control whether the user want to play the song for few minutes or hours.

Thanks :)

Update:
i didn't start writing the code yet, i'm just looking for a sample code to make Timepicker like the in the following app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zodinplex.naturesound&feature=search_result

Comment: What have u tried yet!! What problem you are facing in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps:

1. in TimePicker time change, create a timer and start timer.
2. Create a media player and start media player.
3. on timeout of timer, check if media player is not null, and playing, then stop the media player.

Answer (score 0):

You use TimePicker to get the required time. Then use the countdown timer. Add your desired functionality in the onFinish method of Countdown timer.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //stop media player
    }
  }.start();
```